# Images showing up on android emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, xml, image, drawable

I have an app with 30 images of various resolutions (but all quite big res) and only one drawable folder. so I put them all in that drawable folder but now only a few images are showing up on my phone and if I scroll down my recyclerview to fast my app shuts down. I also already use android:src in my xml. Should I just manually make new folders in explorer and store the files in density folders fitting to the density of the image as been suggested by others? But that makes no sense cause I don't have different density versions of the same images..

Ok I solved it by creating a xxxhdpi folder and putting every image in there.. I don't understand why it works though and why simply having one drawable folder isn't enough.

Comment: please mention some code snippet

Comment: @Piet Baudoin What is the size of the image and what is the dimension (Width and Height) of that image?

Comment: it's all different haha, i have a 1134 x 775, 633 x 600, 945 x 1417, 1134 x 779 etc etc

Comment: Without seeing any relevant code i can't say why it works only like this. But anyway, working with only one picture size is bad practice because you sould always be aware of screen sizes and saving memory. Fortunatly for Android Studio there is a very nice tool called Batch Drawable Importer that you can install to import images to your project. It will create all relavat sizes for you and you dont have to care about it anymore. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer